# How to sort options in select list but keeping one at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, select

Right now I have the following code that goes through my list and sort them alphabetically:

```
<select id="country" class="inputList" name="country">
    <option value="">Select your country</option>
    <option value='0'>Afghanistan</option>
    <option value='1'>Albania</option>
    <option value='2'>Algeria</option>
    <option value='3'>Andorra</option>
    ...
</select>
```

How to make it so the script EXCLUDES the option that has NO value (the first one "Select your Country)?

```
$("#country").html($("#country option").sort(function (a, b) {
return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}))
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The solution as pointed by Offbeatmammal is here:
[sort items in a dropdown list without the first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048762/sort-items-in-a-dropdown-list-without-the-first-item?rq=1)

Comment: I'd probably cheat... strip off the top one, do the sort and then put it back in ... in fact, this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048762/sort-items-in-a-dropdown-list-without-the-first-item?rq=1 - does just that

Comment: Are you using any server side language?  C# allows you to append a list to an asp:DropDownList. Thus removing the need to do this client side.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! I'm looking for this for hours and cannot believe I skipped that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[turning comment into Answer as it solved the problem]

I'd probably cheat... strip off the top one, do the sort and then put it back in ... in fact, this answer - [sort items in a dropdown list without the first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048762/sort-items-in-a-dropdown-list-without-the-first-item?rq=1) - does just that

Answer (score 1):

I usually pull that item out of the list, sort the rest, then reinsert it.